# Call TestCase as Keyword in other TC

Tags: robotframework

I have same simple testcase, I want to use this testcases as keywords. For example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
User Can Add Iteam To Bucket
   same keywords

User Can Perform Checkout Bucket
    User Can Add Iteam To Bucket
    User Can do samething else
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run a test case from another test case.

The solution is to make `User Can Add Iteam To Bucket` into a keyword that you can call from multiple places.